# Cannot install ngx_mruby on Centos 7

Tags: c, ruby, nginx, mruby

I want to install nginx with the module ngx_mruby on centos7, but I ran into the compilation errors.

Following the steps described [here](https://github.com/matsumotory/ngx_mruby/tree/master/docs/install), I did (in my home directory):

```
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.10.1.tar.gz
tar zxvf nginx-1.10.1.tar.gz
git clone git://github.com/matsumoto-r/ngx_mruby.git
cd ngx_mruby
./configure --with-ngx-src-root=/home/vagrant/nginx-1.10.1 with-ngx-config-opt="--prefix=/usr/local/nginx"
make build_mruby
make
```

On `make` process, I got errors:

```
cc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -g   -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I /home/vagrant/ngx_mruby/mruby/src -I /home/vagrant/ngx_mruby/mruby/include -I -g -I -std=gnu99 -I -O3 -I -Wall -I -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -I -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I -Wwrite-strings -I -I/home/vagrant/ngx_mruby/mruby/include -I -I/home/vagrant/ngx_mruby/mruby/build/mrbgems/mruby-pointer/include -I -I/usr/local/include -I /home/vagrant/ngx_mruby/dependence/ngx_devel_kit/objs -I objs/addon/ndk -I objs -I src/http -I src/http/modules -I /home/vagrant/ngx_mruby/dependence/ngx_devel_kit/src \
        -o objs/addon/http/ngx_http_mruby_server.o \
        /home/vagrant/ngx_mruby/src/http/ngx_http_mruby_server.c
In file included from src/core/ngx_core.h:51:0,
                from /home/vagrant/ngx_mruby/src/http/ngx_http_mruby_module.h:12,
                from /home/vagrant/ngx_mruby/src/http/ngx_http_mruby_server.c:7:
/home/vagrant/ngx_mruby/src/http/ngx_http_mruby_server.c: In function ‘ngx_mrb_add_listener’:
/home/vagrant/ngx_mruby/src/http/ngx_http_mruby_server.c:66:20: error: ‘ngx_http_listen_opt_t’ has no member named ‘sockaddr’
   ngx_memcpy(&lsopt.sockaddr.sockaddr, &u.sockaddr, u.socklen);
                     ^
src/core/ngx_string.h:102:49: note: in definition of macro ‘ngx_memcpy’
 #define ngx_memcpy(dst, src, n)   (void) memcpy(dst, src, n)
                                                 ^
/home/vagrant/ngx_mruby/src/http/ngx_http_mruby_server.c:98:29: error: ‘ngx_http_listen_opt_t’ has no member named ‘sockaddr’
   (void)ngx_sock_ntop(&lsopt.sockaddr.sockaddr, lsopt.socklen, lsopt.addr, NGX_SOCKADDR_STRLEN, 1);
                             ^
```

I tried another way to install ngx_mruby:

```
cd ngx_mruby
./configure --enable-dynamic-module --with-ngx-src-root=/home/vagrant/nginx-1.10.1
make build_mruby
make generate_gems_config_dynamic
cd ../nginx-1.10.1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --add-dynamic-module=/home/vagrant/nginx-1.10.1 --add-module=/home/vagrant/nginx-1.10.1/dependence/ngx_devel_kit
make
```

But the same errors happened at `make`.
Then I googled, but it seemed that few people have the same problem.

Is it a common bug, or are there any ways to avoid this error?

Thank you.

---

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.9.4
```